# HX711 Soft WDT Reset

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-ide

I am using the following code to check if the value is 0 e.g there is no weights placed and if so, it will ignore this value and do nothing with it. The code runs correctly but keeps outputting the following:

> Soft WDT reset
>
> > > > stack>>>
>
> ctx: cont sp: 3ffffd70 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 01b0 3fffff20:  00000050
>   00000000 31310010 36323439   3fffff30:  00000000 00000000 00000010
>   00000001   3fffff40:  3ffee408 00000000 00000000 40202927   3fffff50: 
>   4022dff2 a0000000 bf2cc404 3ffe84dc   3fffff60:  3ffee408 bf2cc404
>   3ffee408 40202962   3fffff70:  3ffeeb9c 40202c00 3ffee408 40202996
>   3fffff80:  3ffee448 bf2cc404 3ffee408 40202664   3fffff90:  3fffdad0
>   fffe2d7e 3ffee448 3ffee4b0   3fffffa0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffee480
>   40203848   3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe8514 40100a41
>   <<

If I remove if(reading < 0.01){ the code runs fine. What could be causing this?

```
#include "HX711.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

#define DOUT  D3
#define CLK  D2
const char* ssid = "Curtis"; 
const char* password = "password";


HX711 scale(DOUT, CLK);
float calibration_factor = -118470; //-7050 worked for my 440lb max scale setup
void joinwifi(){
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting");
   while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("success!");
  Serial.print("IP Address is: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  joinwifi();
  Serial.println("HX711 calibration sketch");
  Serial.println("Remove all weight from scale");
  Serial.println("After readings begin, place known weight on scale");
  Serial.println("Press + or a to increase calibration factor");
  Serial.println("Press - or z to decrease calibration factor");
  scale.set_scale();
  scale.tare(); //Reset the scale to 0
  long zero_factor = scale.read_average(); //Get a baseline reading
  Serial.print("Zero factor: "); //This can be used to remove the need to tare the scale. Useful in permanent scale projects.
  Serial.println(zero_factor);
}
void loop() {
  while (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    scale.set_scale(calibration_factor); //Adjust to this calibration factor
    float reading = scale.get_units(1);
    if(reading < 0.01){
      Serial.print("no need");
       Serial.println();
    }
    else{
      Serial.print("Reading: ");
      Serial.print(reading);
      Serial.print(" lbs"); //Change this to kg and re-adjust the calibration factor if you follow SI units like a sane person
      Serial.print(" calibration_factor: ");
      Serial.print(calibration_factor);
      Serial.println();
      if(Serial.available())
      {
        char temp = Serial.read();
        if(temp == '+' || temp == 'a')
          calibration_factor += 10;
        else if(temp == '-' || temp == 'z')
          calibration_factor -= 10;
      }
    }
  }
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    joinwifi();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your code is all running in a `while` inside your loop (which is redundant - loop() loops, hence its name), and you have no delays or `yield()` calls, you are not giving the watchdog the required kick that it needs to stay alive.

Either remove your whiles and turn them into ifs instead, or add `yeild()` calls inside your `while` loops.

Comment: @CurtisBoylan if it solves the issue then please accept Majenko's answer as the solution.